# Passing np.array in np.array

Tags: numpy, numpy-slicing

This was the question and we had to guess the output.

I didn't know we can even pass an array in another array. I got the output but don't understand how.
I am passing 2 arrays - `ind1` and `ind2` in `arr`.

Ques -

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(9, dtype = "float").reshape(3,3)
ind1 = np.array([[1,2],[0,1]])
ind2 = np.array([[0,2],[1,2]])
arr[ind1, ind2].sum()
```

Output

```
array([[3., 8.],
       [1., 5.]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it works (I think) is it takes the two arrays `ind1` and `ind2` and uses the corresponding values as the index of the `arr`. For example,

```
ind1 = [[1,2],[0,1]]
ind1 = [[0,2],[1,2]]
[ind1, ind2] = [[[1, 0],[2, 2]],[[0, 1],[1, 2]]]
arr[1, 0] = 3
arr[2, 2] = 8
arr[0, 1] = 1
arr[1, 2] = 5
```

Comment: Your idea is correct. Here is the official manual: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#basics-indexing. It's actually not a bad read.

Comment: This is more specific to what I was asking, I found this under the link that you provided https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays